# Add a return key value pair to an existing GoogleSignInOptions (gso)

Tags: android-studio, google-signin

The key-value is a client state that is processed this way:

Server -> App -> GSO -> App -> Server

This looks like a very simple question, but I cant seem to find a solution to this problem after much googling. The [documentation on Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder) did not reveal much as well. But I cant seem to trust my self that the Devs missed this very basic task.

Initializing gso looks like this:

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

Then user event sign in launches the intent through this function:

```
private void signIn(key, value) {

    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_G);

}
```

The signIn function possess the key-value pair, but I am stuck how to proceed further.

I also could not find a documentation to tell gso to return the key value pair after user sign in.